# Cannot Edit Database Connection String in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, database-deployment

I have a very unusual bug when trying to connect to a live Azure database via Visual Studio 2022 (17.5.0) using the following connection properties:

- Encryption = true
- Trust Server Certificate = true

The target database connection (read-only) is completely fine when using the Publish Database feature. However, when clicking the Edit > Advanced, Visual Studio automatically sets the Trust Server Certificate to **false**. The Encryption is still set to **true**.

I checked the same scenario using a different machine (lower VS version), but it doesn't override the connection property.

Comment: Just installed VS2022 (v17.5.3) and have the same problem - it's not remembering the change when I set Trust Certificate = True.  This is connecting to an on-prem SQL Server, not Azure.

Comment: I ended up reverting back to using VS2019 where this works fine.

Comment: @Mike, Have you upgraded your Visual Studio since May?  Did that resolve the issue?

Comment: Yes, I'm running the latest VS2022, and no, the problem has not been resolved in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft released a fix for this problem in May 2023.  The fix now is to upgrade Visual Studio to the latest release.

From Microsoft:

> A fix for this issue has been released! Install the most recent release from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/. Thank you for providing valuable feedback which has helped improve the product.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/SSDT-Advanced-Settings-will-not-persist/10233984

Comment: Im using VS2022, latest version 17.9.2 - the problem is back